# Shiny: Using dynamic renderUI's with actionLinks and shinyJS

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I am building a dashboard where I need to create a number of boxes (based on the dataset) provided and then have each box be able to click and show subset boxes.

I can do this if I knew the data beforehand but I am having trouble with creating `link id's` and `showing and hiding` content when creating things ***dynamically***.

Below is the code of how it should function (but using static content)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)


#####/UI/####

header <- dashboardHeader()
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()
body <- dashboardBody(
  useShinyjs(),
  fluidRow(
    uiOutput("box1"),
    uiOutput("box2"),
    uiOutput("box3")
  ),
  fluidRow(
    div(id = "ILRow",
        uiOutput("box1a"),
        uiOutput("box1b"),
        uiOutput("box1c")
        ),
    div(id = "NCRow",
        uiOutput("box2a"),
        uiOutput("box2b")
        ),
    div(id = "INRow",
        uiOutput("box3a")
        )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)



#####/SERVER/####
server <- function(input, output) { 

  CSRbox <- function(description = NULL, linkName = NULL) {

    # the box tags
    withTags(
      # col
      div(
        class = "col-md-2",
        # Widget: user widget style 1
        div(
          class = "box",
          ## Box Header ##
          div(
            actionLink(linkName, NULL, icon = icon("plus-square-o", "fa-2x")),
            h2(description)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  }

  dat <- data.frame(State = c("Illinois","Illinois","Illinois","North Carolina","North Carolina","Indiana"), City = c("Chicago","Niles","Evanston","Charlotte","Raleigh","West Lafayette"))

  output$box1 <- renderUI({
    CSRbox("Illinois", "Ill_Link")
    })

  output$box2 <- renderUI({
    CSRbox("North Carolina", "NC_Link")
  })

  output$box3 <- renderUI({
    CSRbox("Indiana", "IN_Link")
  })

  output$box1a <- renderUI({
    CSRbox("Chicago", "CH_Link")
  })

  output$box1b <- renderUI({
    CSRbox("Niles", "NI_Link")
  })

  output$box1c <- renderUI({
    CSRbox("Evanston", "EV_Link")
  })

  output$box2a <- renderUI({
    CSRbox("Charlotte", "CA_Link")
  })

  output$box2b <- renderUI({
    CSRbox("Raleigh", "RL_Link")
  })

  output$box3a <- renderUI({
    CSRbox("West Lafayette", "WL_Link")
  })

  shinyjs::hide("ILRow")
  shinyjs::hide("NCRow")
  shinyjs::hide("INRow")

  observeEvent(input$Ill_Link, {
    shinyjs::toggle("ILRow")
    shinyjs::hide("NCRow")
    shinyjs::hide("INRow")
  })

  observeEvent(input$NC_Link, {
    shinyjs::toggle("NCRow")
    shinyjs::hide("ILRow")
    shinyjs::hide("INRow")
  })

  observeEvent(input$IN_Link, {
    shinyjs::toggle("INRow")
    shinyjs::hide("ILRow")
    shinyjs::hide("NCRow")
  })



  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Below is the code of creating the boxes dynamically but the functionality doesn't work (this is where I need help!):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)


#####/UI/####

header <- dashboardHeader()
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()
body <- dashboardBody(
  useShinyjs(),
  fluidRow(
    uiOutput("boxLevel1")
  ),
  fluidRow(
    div(id = "LevelDetail",
        uiOutput("boxLevel2")
        )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)



#####/SERVER/####
server <- function(input, output) { 

  CSRbox <- function(description = NULL, linkName = NULL) {

    # the box tags
    withTags(
      # col
      div(
        class = "col-md-2",
        # Widget: user widget style 1
        div(
          class = "box",
          ## Box Header ##
          div(
            actionLink(linkName, NULL, icon = icon("plus-square-o", "fa-2x")),
            h2(description)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  }

  dat <- data.frame(State = c("Illinois","Illinois","Illinois","North Carolina","North Carolina","Indiana"), City = c("Chicago","Niles","Evanston","Charlotte","Raleigh","West Lafayette"))



  output$boxLevel1 <- renderUI({

    lapply(sort(unique(dat$State)), function(name) {

      CSRbox(name, paste0(name,"Link"))

    })
  })

  output$boxLevel2 <- renderUI({

    temp <- dat[dat$State == "Illinois",] #Should be based of off the input$Click of the Input Link. Ex: input$Illinois

    lapply(sort(unique(temp$City)), function(name) {

      CSRbox(name, paste0(name,"Link2"))

    })
  })

  shinyjs::hide("LevelDetail")

  observeEvent(input$IllinoisLink, { #Would need to loop through and make an observeEvent for each possible input$click
    shinyjs::toggle("LevelDetail")
  })

  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**UPDATE**

I have figured out how to track the input ID's which allows me to create the correct subset of boxes dynamically(woo!). I am still having trouble with the `show` and `hide` though. I have figured out how to `show` the subset of boxes but I can't figure out how to `hide` since I am using the `input ID` which doesn't change when pressing on the `link` twice so the `observeEvent` doesn't run. I tried to get just the input of the link which would tell me the `count` of it so I know if it's changed BUT I am getting errors when I use the `input[[input$last_btn]]` (which should be the same as ex: `input$Illinois`). Any help is appreciated! I could add another button separately that would do the hide but that is not ideal.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)


#####/UI/####

header <- dashboardHeader()
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()
body <- dashboardBody(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML("$(document).on('click', '.needed', function () {
                                Shiny.onInputChange('last_btn',this.id);
                             });"))),
  fluidRow(
    uiOutput("boxLevel1"),
    textOutput("lastButtonCliked")
  ),
  fluidRow(
    div(id = "LevelDetail",
        uiOutput("boxLevel2")
        )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)



#####/SERVER/####
server <- function(input, output) { 

  CSRbox <- function(description = NULL, linkName = NULL) {

    # the box tags
    withTags(
      # col
      div(
        class = "col-md-2",
        # Widget: user widget style 1
        div(
          class = "box",
          ## Box Header ##
          div(
            actionLink(linkName, NULL, icon = icon("plus-square-o", "fa-2x"), class="needed"),
            h2(description)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  }

  dat <- data.frame(State = c("Illinois","Illinois","Illinois","North Carolina","North Carolina","Indiana"), City = c("Chicago","Niles","Evanston","Charlotte","Raleigh","West Lafayette"))

  output$boxLevel1 <- renderUI({

    lapply(sort(unique(dat$State)), function(name) {

      CSRbox(name, paste0(name))

    })
  })

  output$boxLevel2 <- renderUI({

    temp <- dat[dat$State == input$last_btn,] #Should be based of off the input$Click of the Input Link. Ex: input$Illinois

    lapply(sort(unique(temp$City)), function(name) {

      CSRbox(name, paste0(name,"Link2"))

    })
  })

  avs <- reactiveValues(
    clickN = NA, #new click
    clickO = NA, #original click
    dataSame = TRUE #data sets are the same
  )

  observe({
    avs$clickN <- input$last_btn
  })

  shinyjs::hide("LevelDetail")

  observeEvent(input$last_btn, {

    avs$dataSame <- identical(avs$clickN, avs$clickO)

    if(!avs$dataSame) {
      shinyjs::show("LevelDetail")
      avs$clickO <- avs$clickN
    } else {
      shinyjs::hide("LevelDetail")
      avs$clickO <- NULL
    }
  })

  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I have not carefully read your post but I think you need to replace `Shiny.onInputChange('last_btn',this.id)` with `Shiny.setInputValue('last_btn',this.id, {priority: 'event'})`. In this way, the `observeEvent` will be trigger if you click twice the button, even though the value of `input$last_btn` does not change.

Comment: Ahhh, I was so close! It works great, thanks @StéphaneLaurent as always! I'm terrible at JS so if I can't find it online, I get lost. Feel free to post that as an answer and I'll accept it.